# O que significa "Darling, just fricken own it"?

Tags: significado

Gostaria muito de saber o que significa essa frase: "Darling, just fricken own it."

Ganhei um quadro escrito isso, mas ainda não pendurei na parede pois não sei o que significa.

Comment: Ana, isto é uma pergunta para o [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions); não é uma pergunta sobre língua portuguesa. De qualquer modo, *own it* signfica 'admitir que é verdade; assumir; assumir frontalmente e com orgulho'. *Fricken* é uma variante/corruptela de *freaking* (*freak* = 'perturbar, chocar, assustar') e é usado como intensificador do mesmo modo que, e provavelmente pela semelhança com *fucking*.

Comment: Gratidão Jacinto!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*[Fricken](http://www.yourdictionary.com/fricken)* é uma maneira diferente de escrever *[fricking](http://www.yourdictionary.com/fricking)*.

Por sua vez, *fricking* dá idea de algo de grande intensidade!

Numa tradução livre seria:

Querido(a), seja apenas totalmente você mesmo.

Comment: É verdade, ou melhor, a palavra é *freaking*. Mas esta pergunta é claramente off-topic. Nestes casos acho que é aceitável ajudar o perguntador nos comentários, mas acho que não deve dar uma resposta a sério. A pergunta vai quase de certeza ser fechada, se a autora não a apagar ela mesma.

Comment: Afinal, [*friking*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fricking) também existe, mas é menos comum que *freaking*. O Merriam-Webster diz que é alteração de [*frigging*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frigging)

Comment: Acho que esta frase têm um significado muito mais próximo e algo como "*Brilha!*" ou "*Mostra-lhes como se faz*" ou "*Dá o teu melhor*" do que própriamente "seja apenas totalmente você mesmo"

Comment: Fiquei confusa! Mas de qualquer maneira, agradeço infinitamente!